# cv::Mat matrices product explained

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm trying to understand the underlying process when multiplying `cv:Mat` matrices in C.

I have an A matrix defined as follows:

```
cv::Mat A(8, 9, CV_32F);
```

I decomposed my matrix using:

```
cv::Mat u, w, vt;
cv::SVDecomp(A, w, u, vt, cv::SVD::MODIFY_A | cv::SVD::FULL_UV);
```

Now I compose the following matrix:

```
cv::Mat temp = u * cv::Mat::diag(w) * vt;
```

Now I want to compare element temp(0,0) with the one computed as follows:

```
u.at<float>(0,0)*w.at<float>(0)*vt.at<float>(0,0) + u.at<float>(0,1)*w.at<float>(1)*vt.at<float>(1,0) + u.at<float>(0,2)*w.at<float>(2)*vt.at<float>(2,0)
```

That should be equal to `temp(0,0)` but I have different numeric values.

In my example:

```
w = [0.712243139743804931640625; 0.701927244663238525390625; 0.0028088125400245189666748046875]

u = [0.77107143402099609375, -0.3598227202892303466796875, 0.5253345966339111328125;
0.4155031144618988037109375, -0.3408392965793609619140625, -0.84331834316253662109375;
0.4824997484683990478515625, 0.868536770343780517578125, -0.113304011523723602294921875]

vt = [-0.3561737239360809326171875, -0.33166158199310302734375, 0.87357938289642333984375;
-0.774875462055206298828125, -0.4176429212093353271484375, -0.474491894245147705078125;
0.522214949131011962890625, -0.845916688442230224609375, -0.10824300348758697509765625]
```

I obtain the following results:

```
cerr << setprecision(100) << temp.at<float>(0,0) << endl;

> 0.000102640246041119098663330078125
```

And

```
cerr << setprecision(100) << u.at<float>(0,0)*w.at<float>(0)*vt.at<float>(0,0) + u.at<float>(0,1)*w.at<float>(1)*vt.at<float>(1,0) + u.at<float>(0,2)*w.at<float>(2)*vt.at<float>(2,0) << endl;

> 0.00010263919830322265625
```

Where does the difference come from? A rounding, certainly, but where?

Comment: *matrix* multiplication does the *mathematical* thing. OpenCV also has *elementwise* multiplication, which is done by a function (cv::multiply or something like that). since you deal with matrix decompositions (SVD), I hope I'm not telling you anything new. -- floats just have 23 bits of mantissa. is the effect you see explainable by that?

Comment: oh, also... *check the type* of all your Mats at every step. float is CV_32F. double is CV_64F. if its type doesn't match what you request in the `<...>` you will get garbage

Comment: All of my elements before and after decomposition are floats (CV_32F). I checked that.
So all have 23 bits of mantissa.
So how my `u*W*vt (0,0)` is not equivalent to `u(0,0)*w(0)*vt(0,0) + u(0,1)*w(1)*vt(1,0) + u(0,2)*w(2)*vt(2,0)`